# Get data-price jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to ask how can i sum data-price from images onclick with jquery?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<body>
<img id="1" src="" data-price="5">
<img id ="2" src="" data-price="10">
<div id="sum"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target the ID of the images, and attach an event handler, then on click, get the data attribute with data()

```
$('#1, #2').on('click', function() {
    alert( $(this).data('price') );
});
```

If you somehow need to sum this up in the #sum element, you should ask specifically about that.

**EDIT:**

and now you did ?

```
$('#1, #2').on('click', function() {
    var data1 = parseInt( $('#1').data('price') ,10);
    var data2 = parseInt( $('#2').data('price') ,10);

    $('#sum').text(data1 + data2);
});
```

Comment: yes in the #sum i mean sorry i didn't mention. for example if i click both images i get sum = 15

Comment: @xiamtos - already added an answer for that, the bottom code will do what you're asking for, just remember the document ready function and you're golden.

Comment: sorry i don't speak very good english, but i will try to explain better .i have 2 images, if i click at first image the sum will become 5 . and if i click at second one then sum will become 15 . something like cart. can be done something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get data-price using `.data()`

Try this:

```
$('#1, #2').click(function() {
    alert( $(this).data('price') );
    var sum = parseInt( $('#1').data('price')) + parseInt( $('#2').data('price'));
    alert(sum);
    $('#sum').html(sum);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/29BRs/2/)

Comment: Why use parseInt? Wouldn’t the person want the exact sum? Without rounding.